# apache не запускается: apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: yii2, apache2

прошу помочь решить проблему запуска апача на ubuntu 20.04:

```
    ~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
    Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
     failed!
    
    ~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
    Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
    
    ~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
    Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
     failed!
    
    ~$ systemctl status apache2.service
    ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor pre>
         Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-01-27 19:33:25 MSK; 16>
           Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
        Process: 862290 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=>
    lines 1-5/5 (END)
    
    ~$ journalctl -xe
    Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
          Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
          Pass -q to turn off this notice.

янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  80>
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1>
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x720"x60.0   67.32  >
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1>
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  >
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  >
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  >
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7850]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1>
янв 28 12:43:14 pcname gsd-color[8109]: failed to create device: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manag>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gsd-color[8109]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 w>
янв 28 12:43:16 pcname gsd-color[8109]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3>
янв 28 12:56:51 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Unable to mount volume HiSuite: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Not authorized to >
янв 28 12:56:52 pcname gvfsd[886082]: Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
янв 28 12:56:52 pcname dbus-daemon[4497]: [session uid=1001 pid=4497] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shel>
янв 28 12:56:52 pcname dbus-daemon[4497]: [session uid=1001 pid=4497] Successfully activated service 'org.gno>
янв 28 12:57:03 pcname sudo[886138]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or direc>
янв 28 12:57:08 pcname sudo[886138]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or direc>
```

со следующего захода ответ изменился:

```
~$ journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
янв 28 13:22:13 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
янв 28 13:23:25 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
янв 28 13:29:16 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
янв 28 13:29:18 pcname gnome-shell[7979]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
янв 28 13:42:36 pcname nautilus[595083]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
янв 28 13:52:57 pcname sudo[887826]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
янв 28 13:53:03 pcname sudo[887826]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
lines 964-1001/1001 (END)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помощь пришла откуда не ждал. команда >> **apachectl -k restart** << дала ответ об ошибке синтаксиса в одном из настроечных файлов:

```
~$ apachectl -k restart
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/username/yii2/frontend/web/] does not exist
AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yii2.conf:
Argument for 'Require all' must be 'granted' or 'denied'
Action '-k restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

после исправления ошибки апач запустился